# Selenium Grid version and Clients

Tags: java, selenium, grid

If I have a Selenium Grid that I want to move to 3.X do all the clients need to also be updated to 3.X?

We are using a combination of Karma and some Selenium client java TestNG tests and while ideally the client Selenium Jar would also match the major version of the Grid how close do the grid and client versions really need to match?

In initial testing it all appears to work but am sure there are compatibility issues that may not be aware of, etc.   The other issue that is slowing me from upgrading the TestNG client selenium dependencies is that we are currently on Java 1.7 so switching to 1.8 and 3.X is a significant jump for us but would like to test against FireFox 52 which appears to need a Selenium Grid 3.X.

Comment: What is the consideration against upgrading the clients to the same version as the hub?

Comment: The issue I have is that currently the clients have written JUNIT tests with Selenium 2.53 using Java 7.    Selenium 3.X would push us to use Java 8 and while we will have to cross this bridge eventually it would take some time to upgrade all products and branches that are currently using the Selenium Grid.    Another possibility is to have two grids (one at 2.53 and one at 3.x but I'm also trying to minimize overhead of maintaining two separate grids if possible

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.. you're asking about the compatibility between the grid and clients (= hub and nodes?), but it seems that all of your project is on 2.53 and if you update one part you'll need all the rest, right?
Also, is your problem only Firefox 52? please try to clarify the question.

Comment: We want to test against ECMAScript 6 which is pushing us to use Firefox 52.   This appears to be pushing us to use Selenium 3.x on the Hub and Nodes.  Currently the teams have written java based JUNIT tests that use Selenium 2.53 jar to communicate with the Selenium Hub to launch the desired browser and write their browser tests.   So my question is really do the clients that communicate with the Hub to get a browser session need to really match the Hub and Node version exactly?  or I guess even better is there any way to get Firefox 52 to work with an existing Selenium 2.53 Hub and Node?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is that you do the upgrade. In any case, you'll have to do it sometime so why postpone it and use patches meanwhile?

It's a good practice to keep your software up to date, especially with browsers, and to do it with Selenium most of the time you only need to change the drivers versions (e.g. chromedriver and geckodriver), but in your case it requires the full upgrade of Java and the selenium-standalone jar. I don't think the process is too painless to do it. After the upgrade you'll have peace of mind for a long while.

Anyways, if you must use a solution right now, I would suggest opening a branch for ECMAScript6 which uses Java 8, Selenium-3.+, and geckodriver and test using `WebDriver` (and not `RemoteWebDriver`) locally.